# Why doesn't this Java regex compile?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the pass number from strings of any of the following formats:

```
PassID_132
PassID_64
Pass_298
Pass_16
```

For this, I constructed the following regex:

```
Pass[I]?[D]?_([\d]{2,3})
```

-and tested it in Eclipse's search dialog. It worked fine.

However, when I use it in code, it doesn't match anything. Here's my code snippet:

```
String idString = filename.replaceAll("Pass[I]?[D]?_([\\d]{2,3})", "$1");
int result = Integer.parseInt(idString);
```

I also tried

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("Pass[I]?[D]?_([\\d]{2,3})")
```

in the *Expressions* window while debugging, but that says "", whereas

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("Pass[I]?[D]?_([0-9]{2,3})")
```

compiled, but didn't match anything. What could be the problem?

Comment: "\\d" already expands to "[0-9]", do not put it into brackets! You can also dump the brackets on single letters like "I" or "D". Try "Pass(?:ID)?_(\\d{2,3})"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing *invalid* with your tegex, but it sucks. You don't need character classes around single character terms. Try this:

```
"Pass(?:ID)?_(\\d{2,3})"
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem actually wasn't that my regex wasn't matching, it was that it didn't cover the entire string, i.e. there was more irellevant text before and after the part matched by the regex, which wasn't removed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Pass[I]?[D]?_([\d]{2,3}) try this:

```
Pass(?:I)?(?:D)?_([\d]{2,3})
```

Comment: Note that his would also match "PassD_123" or "PassI_321"

Comment: True, and so would my regex, but I can afford that. Only Pass_ and PassID_ will appear.

Comment: And still gets the numberic part. I'm just following the pattern followed in the question where the answerer tries to make optional both "I" and "D"